# Postgres sequence getting messed up / overwriting items

Tags: postgresql

Table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE vars_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE vars (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('vars_id_seq'),
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(30)
);
ALTER SEQUENCE vars_id_seq OWNED BY vars.id;
```

I inserted some rows, and all was well. Today, however, when inserting rows, I found that it did one of two things (and both happend at different times):

- It started overwriting existing items when I ran INSERT commands (without specifying an ID, i.e. it should have created a new item)
- It error'd that there was a duplicate key, because it was trying to resume the sequence from 7, for some reason, even though there was an item with ID 7, and items with IDs above 7.

So my question is, conceptually, how could it be that my sequence's current value is lower than the highest ID in my table? Sure, I've deleted rows from it over time, but I would have expected the sequence to keep in sync.

(I know a later way of doing auto-inc in PG is via `SERIAL` / `BIGSERIAL` column types, but for some reason that's not showing as an available type in my DB. I'm from a MySQL background, incidentally.)

Thank you.

====== EDIT

This is what my insert query looks like (via Node):

```
    INSERT INTO ${table}s (${Object.keys(params).map(col => `"${col}"`).join()})
    VALUES (${Array(Object.keys(params).length).fill().map((val, i) => '$'+(i+1)).join()})
    ON CONFLICT (id)
    DO UPDATE SET ${Object.entries(params).map((pair, i) => `"${pair[0]}" = $${i+1}`).join()}
    RETURNING id
```

Comment: Are all inserts into this table using this sequence? A reasonable explanation is someone/something else inserted on it without using the sequence.

Comment: *It started overwriting existing items ...*, are you using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`?

Comment: Thank you, both. I've edited the question to include my query which - yes - does use `ON CONFLICT`. It's a "insert or update" query.

Comment: Well if there are `id`'s beyond the end of latest sequence value then when you do an INSERT a new sequence `id` will be generated for the insert and if it conflicts with one already in use it will UPDATE instead. If you want to use autoincrement it has to be the only thing creating the `id`'s.  I would recommend `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` from here [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).  That will error if something else tries to increment the `id` unless specifically override. Read the docs for more information.

Comment: Yeah, and I suppose that's what I'm trying to figure out, how I ended up with the current sequence value being *lower* than the highest ID in the table. In my example, the current sequence value was 7, yet I had items with ID 15, 16 etc. And every insert has been via the above query or via PGAdmin (using the default column value for the PK, never manually specified.)

Comment: The error is telling you that something/someone is either 1) Creating `id`'s outside the sequence or 2) Manipulating the sequence directly by doing `ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name RESTART` from here [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) or using one of the functions here [Sequence functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html).

Comment: OK thanks, everyone, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Let the database handle all this stuff for you and make it "impossible" to manually handle the id's by using a generated column:

```
CREATE TABLE vars (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly elaborate on what that does? Does that result in an auto-increment setup? I ask because I've read posts about using auto-increment in Postgres, and don't recall seeing that option (they talked about sequences and using serial-type columns.)

Comment: It creates a sequence in the background, owned and maintained by the table. If you try to insert or update the value, you get an error message telling you that this isn't allowed. Makes it much safer to use because people have a tendency to break stuff... It's a SQL Standard thing and it exists in PostgreSQL since version 12. I don't use sequences anymore for ID's, no need for.

Comment: `GENERATED ... AS IDENTITY` is available in Postges 10+ and is the SQL standard compliant way of doing this. You should stick to using it.

Comment: @FrankHeikens,  1) It is available in Postgres 10+.  2) You are still using sequences, so it is entirely possible for people to break stuff  by manipulating the sequence settings directly. It does make managing autoincrement easier.

Comment: OK excellent, I'll convert my tables to use that. Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Of course it's possible to break stuff. But usually I don't give users enough permissions to do it in a predictable manor.

Comment: You are also hoping your users don't read: [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html): *OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE   If this clause is specified, then any values supplied for identity columns will override the default sequence-generated values.*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver At least the wording "overriding system value" is pretty clear in what will happen. And if someone wants to screw-up, that can always be done if you give them the permission to do so.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, conceptually, how could it be that my sequence's current value is lower than the highest ID in my table? Sure, I've deleted rows from it over time, but I would have expected the sequence to keep in sync.

Sequences aren't going to magically update when you delete rows.  If you delete a row in the table with a sequence those sequence numbers are gone.  If you've inserted data *specifying your own sequence number* then you could get out of sync.

Comment: So I haven't inserted any rows where I've specified my own insert ID - I leave that to the default value of the column, i.e. the next number in the sequence. So this being the case, if I delete rows, I would expect that the next insert would continue unaffected, i.e. if I have IDs 1-30, delete rows 20-30, the next insert would use 31 (notwithstanding that Postgres doesn't always increment in 1s). Am I right?

Comment: That is correct.  So I'll admit that it's not 100% clear why you're seeing the issue.